# Hibernate Relationships with inheritance

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, inheritance

I have 4 classes. Entry, EntryTypeOne, EntryTypeTwo and ExampleClass

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="entryType",
        discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public class Entry {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    protected Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    protected String title;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    protected String description;
}
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("One")
public class EntryTypeOne extends Entry{

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<ExampleClass> exampleClasses;
}
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("Two")
public class EntryTypeTwo extends Entry{

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<ExampleClass> exampleClasses;
}
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class ExampleClass {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "exapmleClasses")
    private List<Entry> entries;
}
```

When I start this I get this error:

```
nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: ch.musiciansearch.vingrn.entity.Entry.exampleClasses in ch.musiciansearch.vingrn.entity.ExampleClass.entries
```

My Goal is to make a DB like this:
[DBIMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAdUT.png)

Can I do this without implementing two Lists with the EntryTypes (1 for entrytypeone and 1 for entrytypetwo)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the `@ManyToMany` annotation in a correct way.
Here's how you do ... imagine you have a `Student` entity and `Course` entity.

And students like some courses and don't like others. You want to store information about liked courses in the DB. Here's how you do ...

```
class Student {

// OK, so student class will be the owner of the relationship
// Here we describe the join table, which stores many-to-many data in the DB
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
  name = "course_like", 
  joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student_id"), 
  inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "course_id"))
Set<Course> likedCourses;
}
```

And for course class you do like this ...

```
// Just add a simple mapped by followed by the name of the field in the owning entity
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "likedCourses")
Set<Student> likes;
```

Does this solve your problem ? Let me know in the comments.